# Getting Error:property length missing of an array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular

I want to display list of heroes by iterating through an array I am not able to do as it is giving property length missing of an array.(see screenshot)

My code:In app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero{
    id:number;
    name:string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = {
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor=let hero of heroes"
            [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
  </ul>
      <div *ngIf="selectedHero">
      <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

I am using sublime text so when I hover over it gives me error see screenshot. Some other errors are:
1)Unused label 
2)Left side of comma is unused

How can I fix this errors it is occuring mostly due to `const HEROES` ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUYNA.jpg

Comment: WEll you are trying to assign an object to the `HEROES` array :) Should be `HEROES: Hero[] = [....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining it as array type and assigning as object. Watch your brackets `{ }` to `[ ]`

```
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're following the hero tutorial of Angular, right?
So you may want to take the online example as reference.
First, the array of heroes should be assigned to an array like this:

```
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

In your code, {} is used instead of [] by mistake which causes the error you posted.
Secondly, the array 'heros' used in HTML template is not declared.
It should be declared in AppComponent like this:

```
heroes = HEROES;
```

So that you can iterate it in HTML by *ngFor.

And you can also find the link of full example on this webpage:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Good luck.